# Automatically coloring partial text within cell in Excel

Tags: excel, colors, format, vba

I'm trying to find a way to let's say input the text "3b" in one cell of a specific range of cells in a specific sheet (let's say cells range: J19:O500 and sheet name:WWP), action which will automatically change that cell's background to blue color and the letter "b" to blue color as well (note that only the "b" letter changes to blue color, the goal is having the letter "b" technically "hidden" in the background color and only visually leaving the "3" text in black color). The numbers in the text will be variable (1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, up to 99), but the letters will only be four (b=blue, r=red, g=green, y=yellow). Currently, our teams are manually coloring hundreds of cells every week in a standard file we use, so it would be very valuable if we can make this process automatic by allowing our teams to input the "number" they want for the cell plus a "letter" that will automatically format the cell (b, r, g, y). I understand Macros is an option, but I don't have a lot of experience on that. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code for me site.  Please include what you have tried and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly you would basically like cells in a selected range to display only a number variable, and then color that cell with the specified letter variable. If you would like to do this without using VBA then you can try this **This will require an extra spreadsheet to deal with partial font formatting**

This can be done like so:

1. Create a new sheet in your workbook.
2. Type the following formula in the same cell your real sheet starts with this color formatting. Ex) range is in Sheet2 A1:B3, put this formula in Sheet3 A1:B10

Formula--> `=IFERROR(MID(Sheet2!A1,1,LEN(Sheet2!A1)-1),"")`
*This will return only the numbers in the cells from the other spreadsheet, assuming no other characters proceed after r,g,b,y

**Make sure to copy this formula to the entire range of cells you wish to format**

3. Select the range in sheet 3 that will be worked with (same range in sheet 2)
4. Go to conditional formatting
5. Select New rule
   6.Type in this formula

   =RIGHT(Sheet2!A1:B3,1)="R"

(A1:B3 happens to be my example range. R is for red

7. Choose red formatting
8. Repeat Steps 3 to 7 until each color format is satisfied.
   (simply change the 'R' in step 6's formula to G,B,or Y and change the formatting respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub setRangeColor()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rngDB = Range("J19:o500")

    With rngDB '<~~ Initialize a range
        .Font.Color = vbBlack
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With
    For Each rng In rngDB
        Select Case Right(rng, 1)
        Case "b"
            setTextColor rng, vbBlue
        Case "r"
            setTextColor rng, vbRed
        Case "g"
            setTextColor rng, vbGreen
        Case "y"
            setTextColor rng, vbYellow
        End Select
    Next rng
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub setTextColor(rng As Range, myColor As Long)
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Len(rng)
    rng.Characters(n, 1).Font.Color = myColor
    rng.Interior.Color = myColor
End Sub
```